# Windows 7 restore system caused personal data files to be reverted

Tags: backup, windows-7, system-restore

After an unexpected crash, windows 7 booted up into a mode that I'm not familiar with where it asked to restore the system to a previous save point to correct some problem. After saying OK to it I've come to find a file that was actively being worked on (.nsis extension, text file, it's a windows installer script) was reverted (2 days work lost) very much unexpectedly.

I can't find a backup of the file anywhere and so I'm wondering, in the process of reverting to a previous save point, does windows backup its work anywhere?

Comment: I don't think previous versions would survive a previous save point restore, even if it was turned on.  You can try it by r-clicking the file and seeing if the previous versions tab has another version on disk.  Losing two days works sucks, good luck.

Comment: Thanks for that, you could post that as an answer. I did check, nothing there, but I didn't know those options were there previously.

Comment: Eh, it wasn't really an answer...  Another suggetsion would be to pull the drive and run utilities on it.. (as you are using the drive you are overwriting data that might still be on there).  Just food for thought. Again, not realy an answer, but might help you get to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System Restore *never* deletes files.  However, there have been issues similar to yours.  Check this [article](http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-35141-lost-my-doc-media-files-after-system-restore) out and see if it helps.